# Support newer api functions if available

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-3.0-honeycomb

**My Question:** Can I support an older api and use functions of a newer api if available?

**My Situation:** I'm building a simple app that I want to support some advanced functions with the UI if available. But the API level I'm supporting is 13 so I can support Android 3.2.  Specifically, I want to use the `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_*` variables, but those are not available in api level 13.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can check that at runtime:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   // my code using HC API
} else {
   // code that works on older API
}
```

and you have to set `android:targetSdkVersion` of your app's Manifest to **highest** API version you want to support, otherwise you will not be able to build it.

Please see [this `<uses-sdk>` related article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: So if I have my target api at a higher level will that not cause my app to be unavailable to users on lower versions?

Comment: Absolutely not. Things that could availability of your app for some devices are `minSdkVersion` or `<supports-screens>`, but not `targetSdkVersion`. Please see the article I linked to in updated answer.

Comment: No, that is what the min api level is for. This answer is correct.